# How to get out of my while loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

So my issue with my code is that even though I have enter the correctly guessed word, my code still reads it as incorrect; therefore, asks me to try again.  How do I get out of this loop?  Appreciate it.

```
 import random

 count = 1
 word = ['orange' , 'apple' , 'chicken' , 'python' , 'zynga'] #original list
 randomWord = list(random.choice(word)) #defining randomWord to make sure random
 choice jumbled = ""
 length = len(randomWord)

 for wordLoop in range(length):

    randomLetter = random.choice(randomWord)
    randomWord.remove(randomLetter)
    jumbled = jumbled + randomLetter

 print("The jumbled word is:", jumbled)
 guess = input("Please enter your guess: ").strip().lower()

 while guess != randomWord:
      print("Try again.")
      guess = input("Please enter your guess: ").strip().lower()
      count += 1
      if guess == randomWord:
       print("You got it!")
       print("Number of guesses it took to get the right answer: ", count)
```

Comment: break exists a loop

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of a question which is about a for loop when this question here is about a while loop? More over this question is not even about getting out of a while loop. It should be something like "Why my while condition always evaluates true".

Comment: @shove you may vote to reopen. Closing review was https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15181216

Comment: @Cœur thanks for the hint. I would vote for reopen if i could. It seems that i do not have enough reputation. But i think my answer reached OP and may have helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
randomWord.remove(randomLetter)
```

This line removes every letter from your variable.
you can use:

```
randomWord2 = randomWord.copy()
for wordLoop in range(length):
    randomLetter = random.choice(randomWord2)
    randomWord2.remove(randomLetter)
    jumbled = jumbled + randomLetter
```

This will copy your variable. If you wont do this your result will be two names for the same variable.

And you compare a list with a string try this instead:

```
while guess != ''.join(randomWord):
```

It will convert your list back into a string.